# Poisson Regression with overload of zeroes SAS

Tags: count, model, sas, distribution, poisson

I am testing different models for the best fit and most robust statistics to my data. My dataset contains over 50000 observations, approx. over 99.3% of the data are zeroes - such 0.7% are actual events.

Eventually see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvmC5.jpg

I search to find the best fit of the following models; Logistic, Poisson, NB, ZIP, ZINB, PLH, NBLH. (NB: Negative-binomial, ZI: Zero-Inflated, P: Poisson, LH: Logit Hurdle)

The first way I tried doing this was by estimating the binary response with logistic regression.

My questions: Can I use Poisson on the binary variable or should I instead impose the binary with some integer values? For instance with the associated loss; if y=1 then y_val=y*loss. In my case, the variance of y_val becomes approx. 2.5E9. I held to use the binary variable because it does not matter, in this purpose, what the company defaulted with, default is default no matter the amount.

Both with logistic regression and Poisson, I got some terrible statistic: Very high deviance value (and 0 p-value), terrible estimates (=many of the estimated parameters are 0 -> odds ratio =1), very low confidence intervals, everything seems to be 'wrong'. If I transform the response variable to log(y_val) for y>1 in Poisson the statistics seem to get better - however, this is against the assumptions of integer count response in Poisson.

I briefly have tested the ZINB, it does not change the statistics significantly (=it does not help at all in this case).

Does there exist any proper way of dealing with such a dataset? I am interested in achieving the best fit for my data (about startup business' and their default status).

The data are cleaned and ready to be fitted. Is there anything I should be aware of that I don't have mentioned?

I use the genmod procedure in SAS with dist=Poisson, zinb, zip etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest migrating this question to https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: @J_Lard: I will try - thank you.

Comment: You may want to step out of these options and see if a random forest will work. It may not but its worth a shot if this is for predictions.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my rep is too low to comment, so it has to be an answer.

You should consider undersampling technique before using any regression/model, because your target is below 5%, which makes it extremely difficult to to predict.

Undersampling is a method of cutting out non-target events, in order to increase target ratio, I really recommend considering it, I got to use it once in my practice, and it seemed pretty helpful

Comment: Thanks for advice! I tried it for some months ago and ended up having over 10% of defaults. The problem is, that I am afraid of losing information with over/undersampling. 

I should change my question, it is more the statistical values I want to be "good".